# Trouble with simple animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, toggle

This code works just on JSfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/KhcvR/2016/

```js
$(".sort").toggle(function() {
    $(".sort").animate({
        width: '90%'
    });
}, function() {
    $(".sort").animate({
        width: '50px'
    });
});
```

```css
.sort {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #EA932E;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sort"></div>
```

Comment: What's the problem? The code works fine

Comment: Works here too when put in a snippet but ONLY with jQuery < 1.8

Comment: What is the question? Check that your application isn't blocking mixed-SSL content.

Comment: Funny I have marked this as a duplicate of my own question from 3 years ago. It does not work after jQuery 1.8 since fn.toggle(function,function) disappeared

Comment: Resolved the problem,thanks